# How to achieve UNION functionality in Oracle without using UNION clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables TAB1 and TAB2 of same structure with columns col1 and col2 of same data type respectively. I want a workaround in SQL without using UNION to find out UNION of two tables.

Comment: If you are looking for an `union`, why don't you want to use `union`? Is it a whim or you have some requirement by some unknown reason?

Comment: Is this an *exam question*? Could you use `union` **`ALL`** and `distinct`? Or simple defiene a view with `UNION` and than query `select * from view` (without `UNION`).

Comment: You must know that `UNION` acts as `DISTINCT` with the datasets your are working. If you use `UNION ALL` instead, duplicated records are returned. Maybe the question is addressed in this direction.

Comment: Use of UNION or any set operator is not allowed. Its a business requirement

Comment: Must be a very stupid business requirement. What's next, grouping without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: WHY is it a BUSINESS requirement? The "business" side of things should not be permitted to have any opinion on how problems are solved on the technical end. Why do the "business" people even know about the technical concept of "set operations"? Sorry, but the reason you gave makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: It makes no sense to pay Oracle a huge licensing fee and then not use a feature if it provides a benefit. That "if" should be executed by the people implementing a solution, not the people who ordered the feature being added. Does it make sense for a lieutenant to order a platoon to take a hill without their weapons?

Comment: The business means functions like sales, customer services, product development, HR. The use or avoidance of specific database features cannot be a business requirement. Why is HR telling you not to use UNION? Do they also instruct C# programmers they need a solution without `Console.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why someone may need this, but just for fun:

**NB: never use this approach in real production code! Use `Union` properly instead!**

```sql
select
   nvl(t1.t_id,t2.t_id) t_id
  ,nvl(t1.COL1,t2.COL2) COL_DATA
from (select 1 t_id, COL1 from TAB1) t1
     full outer join
     (select 2 t_id, COL2 from TAB2) t2
     on t1.t_id = t2.t_id
order by 1,2;
```

Example with test data:

```sql
with 
 TAB1(COL1) as (select 1 from dual)
,TAB2(COL2) as (select level from dual connect by level<=10)
select
   nvl(t1.t_id,t2.t_id) t_id
  ,nvl(t1.COL1,t2.COL2) COL_DATA
from (select 1 t_id, COL1 from TAB1) t1
     full outer join
     (select 2 t_id, COL2 from TAB2) t2
     on t1.t_id = t2.t_id
order by 1;

      T_ID   COL_DATA
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          1
         2          2
         2          3
         2          4
         2          5
         2          6
         2          7
         2          8
         2          9
         2         10

11 rows selected.
```

Comment: On quick inspection, I believe this will replicate `union all`, rather than `union`. Right? If so, you may still need to add a `distinct` in the outer `select`.

Comment: Knowing that exists the `UNION` operator... I was lazy, to be honest. But nice answer and nice comment

Comment: Yes, I did it so for more readability to show where each record is taken from, so didn't use distinct - I don't think it may be difficult for someone to add `distinct` properly. And that's just for fun, not for real use.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, @SayanMalakshinov's  solution can be a bit simpler

```
with 
 TAB1(COL1) as (select 1 from dual)
,TAB2(COL2) as (select level from dual connect by level<=10)
select
  nvl(t1.COL1, t2.COL2) COL_DATA
from TAB1 t1
full outer join TAB2 t2 on 1=2
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be the solution

```
select
case when t1.col1=t2.col1 then t1.col1 else nvl(t2.col1,t1.col1) end result
from temp1 t1
full outer join temp2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1
order by 1;
```